# Keras backend Custom Loss Function

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I am Trying to calculate `(tp+tn)/total_samples` as my custom loss function. I know how to do this in list and list comprehension but there is no way i guess that i can convert `y_true` and `y_pred` to list.

The code I have written so far is:

```
def CustomLossFunction(y_true, y_pred):
   y_true_mask_less_zero = K.less(y_true, 0)
   y_true_mask_greater_zero = K.greater(y_true, 0)

   y_pred_mask_less_zero = K.less(y_pred, 0)
   y_pred_mask_greater_zero = K.greater(y_pred, 0)

   t_zeros = K.equal(y_pred_mask_less_zero, y_true_mask_less_zero)
   t_ones = K.equal(y_pred_mask_greater_zero, y_true_mask_greater_zero)
```

Now I need to sum total number of TRUES in t_zeros and t_ones and add them up and divide them by total samples

I got an error on this line:

```
sum_of_true_negatives = K.sum(t_zeros)
```

> Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType bool not in list of allowed values: float32, float64, int32, uint8, int16

**Questions:**

- is there any built in loss function for "(tp+tn)/total_samples"
- if not then how to calculate using Keras backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must `cast` your boolean tensors to float before putting them into calculations.

But a warning, so you don't waste your time:

> This loss function will not work because it's not differentiable. You can't simply discard the "continuity" existing in `y_pred` like that. (You will get errors like "None values not supported" or "An operation has None for gradient")

Use some of the existing standard functions for classification, such as `binary_crossentropy` or `categorical_crossentropy`.

**Casting:**

```
t_zeros = K.cast(t_zeros, K.floatx())
t_ones = K.cast(t_ones, K.floatx())
```